Is it possible to change the title of a GitHub action based on data not available until some jobs have run?
I am using Actions in GitHub Enterprise. I would like to be able to change the title of a run with information not available at the time it is triggered, but that becomes available during the run.
I am aware of the run-name feature as discussed here and documented here. However, as described that seems to require the name to be known at the start of the run.

That is true, the run-name can have dynamic values only from github and inputs contexts that are fixed before the run starts and are read-only during the run.
